# How to select a particular item from existing select options in ionic 3 from the .ts?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedGender" placeholder="SelectGender (ngModelChange)="checkRel()" >
      <ion-option [value]="m">Male</ion-option>
      <ion-option [value]="f">Female</ion-option>
      <ion-option [value]="O">Others</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

How to dynamically select any of the existing option based on some condition?

Comment: just assign the value to `selectedGender` that you want to display dynamically

Comment: if(this.gender == "male" || this.gender == "Male"){
        this.selectedGender = "m";
      }

      if(this.gender == "female" || this.gender == "Female"){
        this.selectedGender = "f";
      } }     i am doing this but its not working

Comment: I have just assign the data to the ngModel variable and it shows the assigned data for me

Comment: unable to get it still

Answer (score 0):

You ion-option values are being treated as numbers. You need to assign them as strings.

```
<ion-option [value]="'m'">Male</ion-option>
```

OR Simply...

```
<ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
```